# Trying to list products as Men, Women and Store on Woopress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to list products as following.

1. Men: Contains all the products related to men.
2. Women: Contains all the products related to women.
3. Brand: Contains all the brands, which leads to products both men and
   women.

As you can see this isnt a clear hierarchy. I'm thinking about way how we can do this?

Comment: What's wrong with product categories?

Comment: as far as my understanding is, categories have to be linear. you have categories like catA has sub category catB and so on. but in my case i have categories Men and Women. Brand can be sub category of men and women. but in this case Brand will not have both men and women items.

Comment: Ok, maybe instead of categories you have two taxonomies: vendor and gender. Then you can combine archives with pretty permalinks: https://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to create three product category to separate all these product. You need to do .....
1. Go to Products -> Categories. Then you need to add three categories like Men Women and Brand.
2. After that, When you add product or edit your product, you just need to check the category of the product.

[image]

[image]